# Hyperledger Fabric CA: Where can we find list of environment variables?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

From the [docs](https://fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html):

> The Fabric CA provides 3 ways to configure settings on the Fabric CA
>   server and client. The precedence order is:
>
> 1. CLI flags
> 2. Environment variables
> 3. Configuration file

Where can we find list of applicable Environment variables with their description? e.g., we know `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME` can be used to set the home directory. What about all the rest env variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the CLI flags can be set via environment variables.
All environment variables start with `FABRIC_CA_SERVER` and then you simply append the command line flag using `_` as a separator and replace `.` with `_`; so

`--address`  -> `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_ADDRESS`
`--ca.keyfile` -> `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE`

The same concept applies for values in the config file as well; you just append them to `FABRIC_CA_SERVER` using `_` for each level of the tree.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Comment: @Gari Singh How about other Fabric CLI commands? I know that peer, for example, uses CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID and CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH, among others. Do you happen to know if there is a list of variables per CLI command, or something equivalent? Is it that for the peer command all variables start with CORE_PEER, then an underscore and then the name of the flag? How about configtxgen? Are there variables starting with CORE_CONFIGTXGEN? It's really amazing that there doesn't seem to be any documentation on something so important. Please prove me wrong.

Comment: It's quite some time since this question and answer, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for all cli flags. I am specifically looking to pass the `boot` flag as environmental variable but the pattern 'breaks' in the case of `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_BOOT`.